# Finding a value of $a$ so that there is at least 1 injective linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Say that $v_1 = (1, 2, -2), v_2 = (3, 6, -4), v_3 = (0, 1, a^2-1)$ and $w_1 = (2, -a^2, -1), w_2 = (4, 6-2a, 2), w_3 = (0, 3, 2)$.

Part A asks for which values of a are $v_1, v_2, v_3$ linearly independent. I solved this by finding when the determinant of the matrix with $v_1, v_2, v_3$ is not equal to zero. The determinant is $-2$ for all values of $a$ so this is true for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Part B asks for which value of a there is at least 1 injective linear function $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $F(v_1) = w_1, F(v_2) = w_2, F(v_3) = w_3$. I don't have an immediate idea for this part of the question. I know that a function is injective if and only if the kernel is equal to zero, but I'm not sure what to do with that information.

Part C asks for which value of a is there a unique injective linear function $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $F(v_1) = w_1, F(v_2) = w_2, F(v_3) = w_3$. Again I am not sure what to do here.

Comment: Hint: Are the $w_k$ linearly independent?

Comment: $w_k$ are linearly independent if $a \neq 0$ and $a \neq 1$. How does this relate to the injectivity of the function?

Comment: What if the images of the $v_i$ aren’t linearly independent?

Comment: It might help to note that since the domain and codomain are the same dimension, $F$ is also injective if and only it is surjective. This follows from the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).